# how to repeat an executable with different parameters?

Tags: shell, executable

I have an executable file to analyse an image . In the shell I write `./analyse img_001.jpg`  and it returns 1 number.
I looked for a solution to analyse my 999 images ( img_001.jpg to img_999.jpg) with the use of a script ( i don't really wish to do it manually ) and I need a hint please.

Is it possible to have something like `./script.sh` that returns me the 999 numbers?

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, you can simply use brace expansion:

```
for i in {1..999}; do
    printf "img_%03d.jpg\n" $i
done
```

This will print out:

```
img_001.jpg
img_002.jpg
...
img_998.jpg
img_999.jpg
```

To run your script using these as arguments you can use:

```
for i in {1..999}; do
    ./analyse $(printf "img_%03d.jpg" $i)
done
```

You could also replace the brace expansion with `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 999); do
```

Comment: In bash version 4 or later {000..999} expands directly to the zero padded numbers, so printf is not needed anynore